# Can we solve for $a$ in $b(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty b(s)a(x,s)ds$

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-equations

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $$b(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty b(s)a(x,s)ds.$$  If it helps, we can assume that $a, b$ are continuous, nonnegative, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ of $a$ or $b$ are both bounded.

> Two questions: (1) Is $a$ unique?  and (2) to what extent can we solve for $a$?

Comment: This looks like a special case of Fredholm Integral Equations of the Second Kind, with f(x) = 0, $\lambda$ = 1, and where $\phi$ is known instead of the Kernel.  That might be useful.

Comment: A corresponding matrix problem:  Given an eigenvector $b$ for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, solve for the matrix.  Answer: no, $A$ is not unique.

Comment: This sounds helpful, but I'm not sure what you mean: in what sense is that a corresopnding matrix problem?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ is an inner product.  That's a very interesting way to look at this problem.

Answer (score 5):

The solution for your integral equation is the Dirac Delta function, that is $$a(x,s) = \delta(s-x).$$ It is known as the sifting propert of the dirac delta function.

Comment: the Dirac delta function is not continuous, nor bounded.

Comment: He said "if it helps, we assume continuity and boundedness".

Comment: Note that, Dirac delta function is not a function in the usual sense! Why?

Comment: The dirac delta is a functional and not a function. This is of course an extent to which the equation can be solved by means of distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueness is not necessarily guaranteed. For example, when definable, take $a(x,s)=\frac{b(x)}{b(s)}f(s)$ where $f$ is any probability density, that is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s) ds=1$.